# Undefined startup parameter if its name contains a hyphen, e.g. "sap-system"

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

A general Fiori launchpad tile is set up with a parameter 'sap-system=SystemAlias'.

Logging `this.getComponentData().startupParameters` returns:

```
{sap-system: Array(1)}
```

I've faced the issue to access the parameter by calling

```js
let sSystem = this.getComponentData().startupParameters.sap-system[0];
```

The w3schools in [Naming Conventions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp) says that

> Hyphens are not allowed in JavaScript names.

Is there a way to access such parameters with a hyphen, e.g. "sap-system"?

Comment: @boghyon-hoffmann thank you. the approach works for my case.